# SwiftUI View doesn't change when using button and @State / @Binding

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

Long story short this is an onboarding view after a user goes through auth. My main navigation of the app uses navigationview but I can't use that for onboarding. I've put a fullscreencover over the main screen for this onboarding stuff.

However, when trying to simply navigate between the views from different files between the onboarding screens, the button doesn't show the other view. I've tried everything under the son from @Appstorage and @Environment stuff but can't get it to work.

Also please note I cut off the bottom of the rest of the file as that had nothing to do with this logic.

```
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingTestView: View {
    @State var shouldShowOnboarding = true
    var body: some View {
        if shouldShowOnboarding {
            OffsetChoicesView(shouldShowOnboarding: $shouldShowOnboarding)
        }
        if shouldShowOnboarding == false {
            PersonalInfoView()
        }
    }
}

struct OnboardingTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnboardingTestView()
    }
}

//*********************************************************************
//OffsetChoicesView

struct OffsetChoicesView: View {
    @Binding var shouldShowOnboarding: Bool
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9803921569, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            VStack {

            Progress1View()
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                .padding(.top)
            
            Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    shouldShowOnboarding = false
                }) {
                    NextButtonView()
                        .padding(.top)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                }
            
            }
```

Comment: Instead of `if shouldShowOnboarding == false {` try just an `else {`

Comment: Also, try embedding your if statement inside a `VStack` or `Group`

Comment: this code shows `PersonalInfoView` on `NextButtonView` button tap to me. p.s. even if you're using `fullScreenCover`, you can declare one more `NavigationView` inside that one and use `NavigationLink` without a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this - utilizes `@AppStorage`

I was not quite sure what the `OffsetChoiceView()` parameters are supposed to be.. so I just removed them in the example. This should be whatever your onboarding view is called.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingTestView: View {
    //@State var shouldShowOnboarding = true
    
    @AppStorage("showOnboarding") var showOnboarding: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        if (showOnboarding == true) {
            OffsetChoicesView()
        } else if (showOnboarding == false) {
            PersonalInfoView()
        }
    }
}

struct OnboardingTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnboardingTestView()
    }
}

//*********************************************************************
//OffsetChoicesView

struct OffsetChoicesView: View {
    //@Binding var shouldShowOnboarding: Bool
    @AppStorage("showOnboarding") var showOnboarding: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9803921569, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            VStack {

            Progress1View()
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                .padding(.top)
            
            Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    showOnboarding = false
                }) {
                    NextButtonView()
                        .padding(.top)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                }
            
            }
```

Comment: Cant you use `Bool` with `AppStorage` ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Try changing AppStorage to the following (on mobile, so best guess): @AppStorage("showOnboarding") var showOnboarding: Bool = false